# How can I get "Associated Entitlements" for a product in RevenueCat?

Tags: flutter, revenuecat

I have multiple entitlements in my app and I want to group the products under respective entitlement on my paywall. I am able to get only purchased entitlements from `getPurchaserInfo`. Is their a way to get the "Associated Entitlements" for all products (both purchased and not purchased)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response from RevenueCat team:

> This association isn’t returned on the products through the API currently, so I’m not sure if there would be a straightforward way to do this. However, the use-case makes complete sense and I’ll share this with our engineering team as a feature request. I think it would require a change to the GET /offerings API to add the association, and an update to the  SDKs to parse the new API response appropriately.
> There isn’t a workaround I can think of that doesn’t involve some level of hardcoding .